# Refactoring large methods in NUnit tests

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

How do I manage large tests. I'm testing a webapplication and one of the features is, making a new order, where the user has to go through a couple of forms before the order will be made.

I can write a selenium test in C# that tests the entire flow of making a new order. But that test would rather turn out quite large.

The simplified flow looks like this:

1. Select 1 or more customers for the order
2. Select 1 or more products associated with the selected customers
3. Add some metadata about the order, such as name, who has to complete it, date, comments, etc.

There are a few subforms where the user has to search for customers and for products.

Now I can write one (large) test that walks through the entire primary flow. But that test could easily result in a method with 100+ lines.
And I also want to test certain alternative flows, which would result in a method that could easily be 80% the same as the normal flow method.

However, I know you shouldn't write tests that depend on each other. So there's my dilemma. My code will look something like this

```
[test]
public void NormalFlow()
{
    //Execute the first two steps
    //Around 100 lines

    //Execute the third step normally
    //around 50 lines
}

[test]
public void AlternativeFlow()
{
    //Execute the first two steps
    //Around 100 lines

    //Execute the third step, but follow alternative flow
    //around 50 lines
}
```

There's a lot of duplicate code, but I can't just start at the third step, so I've got to walk through the first two steps. I can't separate those first two steps as a separate test, because that would make my tests dependent on each other.

What should I do? How do I avoid duplicating all of my code without creating dependent tests?

Comment: You can use the  [Setup](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10) attribute to setup the tests if first two steps is same for all the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I can write one (large) test that walks through the entire primary
>   flow. But that test could easily result in a method with 100+ lines.
>   And I also want to test certain alternative flows, which would result
>   in a method that could easily be 80% the same as the normal flow
>   method.

Just because you're writing a test that does several things, doesn't mean you have to put it all in a single method.  Refactoring your test code to make sure it is of an appropriate quality is an important part of the development process.

> I know you shouldn't write tests that depend on each other.

Whilst this is true, I think you may be taking it a bit literally.  Based on your description of the system, this would be an example of two tests that *depend* on each other:

**Test One**
Create a new order for customer XXX.

**Test Two**
Add product YYY to an open order for customer XXX.

Test Two is dependent on Test One, because if Test One hasn't executed / has failed Test Two will also fail and it may not be obvious why.

This is different from two related tests that aren't dependent on each other.  So, the alternative to the above would be:

**Test One** Create  a new order for customer XXX.

**Test Two** Create a new order for customer ZZZ and add product YYY to the order.

Each test case is self contained and can be run in isolation.  As you've said, this is essentially because Test Two is performing a lot of the same processing that Test One is.  This is ok, but it doesn't mean that all of the code for Test Two has to be in a single method.  If you were writing production code, you would probably look at your code, identify duplication and refactor it out either into different methods or classes that could be reused.  If this makes your test code easier to read, then it's absolutely the right thing to do.

So from your example code you might have something like this:

```
[Test]
public void NormalFlow()
{
    var sessionDetails = Logon(customerCredentials);

    var openOrder = CreateOrder(sessionDetails);

    AddProductToOrder(openOrder, productDetails);

    AddMetaDataToOrder(openOrder, metaData);
}

[Test]
public void AlternativeFlow()
{
    var sessionDetails = Logon(customerCredentials);

    var openOrder = CreateOrder(sessionDetails);

    AddProductToOrder(openOrder, productDetails);

    AddMetaDataToOrder(openOrder, alternateFlowMetaData);
}
```

The shared/duplicate code is pushed into the shared methods.  Just because the code is shared, doesn't mean the tests are dependent.

As has been said in the comments by @Sriram Sakthivel, another thing that you can do if you have the same code at the start of every test (for example logging on) is to put that into a method that's marked up with the `Setup` attribute. Remember, the goal is to make your test code easy to write/understand and maintain.